# How to get second last url segment

Tags: templating, url, segments

I'm setting up a dynamic thank-you page for all forms added to the site. Client can add forms with freeform to any page and I have set the return url to this:

```
{{ form.renderTag({
    class: "w-full pb-4",
    returnUrl: craft.app.request.absoluteUrl ~ 'thank-you/'
    }) }}
```

Which works. However on the thank-you page I would like to set the entry to be the slug of the **second last url segment**

i.e. if the thank you page is https://domain.com/foo/bar/thank-you then I need to be able to get **bar** however if the url is https://domain.com/foo/thank-you then I need to get **foo**

How can I do this? if only `craft.app.getSecondLastSegment()` were a thing.

so ideally something simpler than this:

````
{% set entrySlug = "" %}

{% if craft.app.request.getSegment('4')|length %}
  {% set entrySlug  = craft.app.request.getSegment('3') %}
{% elseif craft.app.request.getSegment('3')|length %}
  {% set entrySlug  = craft.app.request.getSegment('2') %}
{% elseif craft.app.request.getSegment('2')|length %}
{% else %}
  {% set entrySlug  = craft.app.request.getSegment('1') %}
{% endif %}```
````

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use negative numbers as the parameter for `segment` which then counts from right to left.

So `{{ craft.app.request.segment(-1) }}` will get the last segment.

And... `{{ craft.app.request.segment(-2) }}` will get the next to last segment

Comment: That's brilliant

Comment: @foamcow thanks! i didn't know about that

Answer (score 1):

```
{% if craft.app.request.segments|length > 1 %}
  {% set secondToLast = craft.app.request.segments|slice(-2, 1)|first %}
{% else %}
  no second to last
{% endif %}
{{ secondToLast }}
```

[getSegments()](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-web-request.html#method-getsegments) returns an array of segments

in line 1: check if there is a second to last item

[slice](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)(-2, 1): -2 target second to last item and you only that one so second parameter is 1

`|first` is because slice returns an array

---

this solution need some tests and some consideration
for example [Craft docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-web-request.html#method-getsegments) says:

> Note that the segments will not include the control panel trigger if
>   it’s a control panel request, or the page trigger or page number if
>   it’s a paginated request.